# feathers.js - discard hook not working in authentication.js

Tags: feathersjs

I am using Feathers.js for the backend.

This is the original response from POST /authentication

```json
{
    "accessToken": "XXXXX",
    "authentication": {
        "strategy": "local",
        "accessToken": "XXXXX",
        "payload": {
            "iat": 1616402936,
            "exp": 1616489336,
            "aud": "https://yourdomain.com",
            "iss": "feathers",
            "sub": "c15ef318-68fc-471c-9710-52f14d87abda",
            "jti": "57d103e1-c81b-4fc6-8bbe-952b74aaf8e3"
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "id": "c15ef320-68fc-471c-9710-52f14d87ccda",
        "email": "abc.abc@abc.com",
    }
}
```

I want to discard the `accessToken` field from the response, so I modified `authentication.js` as:

```js
const { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');
const { expressOauth } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');
const { discard, iff, isProvider, lowerCase } = require('feathers-hooks-common')

module.exports = app => {
  const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());

  authentication.hooks = {
    before: {
      create: [lowerCase('email')],
      update: [lowerCase('email')],
      patch: [lowerCase('email')],
    },
    after: {
      create: [discard('accessToken')]
    }
  };

  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());
};
```

But nothing changes after I've changed the code to the above one.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook function should be put in the last.

```
...
module.exports = app => {
  const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());
 
  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());

  app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [lowerCase('email')],
      update: [lowerCase('email')],
      patch: [lowerCase('email')],
    },
    after: {
      create: [
        discard('authentication')
      ]
    }
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [API documentation on registering hooks](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#registering-hooks) it should be `app.service('/authentication').hooks(hooks)`:

```
const { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');
const { expressOauth } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');
const { discard, iff, isProvider, lowerCase } = require('feathers-hooks-common')

module.exports = app => {
  const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());

  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.service('/authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [lowerCase('email')],
      update: [lowerCase('email')],
      patch: [lowerCase('email')],
    },
    after: {
      create: [discard('accessToken')]
    }
  });
  app.configure(expressOauth());
};
```

Comment: TypeError: this.hooks is not a function